# What is the TypeScript type of an array of different Angular components?

Tags: angular, typescript

In my app there are a lot of various components.
I would like to have an array of components.
There is no rule of what components can be in the array. The only rule is that these should be Angular components.

How to define properly a TypeScript type of an array of Angular components?

Something like:

`myComponents: AngularComponent[];`

Specifically what is the proper replacement for my imagined "AngularComponent" class?

Comment: `any[]`. You're never going to need to type them more than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an interface Component:

`myComponents:Component[]`

Comment: It's not an interface, it's a decorator, and this won't work. Unless you had a different `Component` in mind? What is it?

Comment: It is declared in @angular/core 'export declare interface Component extends Directive'

Comment: It's just a type declaration file. And if you try to use Component as a type and assign an instance of an Angular component to it, you'll get something like `Type 'TestComponent' has no properties in common with type 'Component'.`.